# PGFPlots + TikZ: Stranger Beamer behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, beamer-metropolis

I am trying to include a `PGFPlots` + `TikZ` figure in a `beamer` presentation made with the `metropolis` theme. If I compile the figure in a normal `article` class (or `standalone`), the figure is fine. The code for the figure is the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\textwidth,
        height=8cm,
        hide y axis,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
        xticklabels={$\bar x-3s$,$\bar x-2s$,$\bar x-s$,$\bar x$,$\bar x+s$,$\bar x+2s$,$\bar x+3s$},
        xmin = -3.5,
        xmax = 3.5,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 0.9,
    ]
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-3,0.85);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-2,0.7);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-1,0.55);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1,0.55);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:2,0.7);
    \draw[dashed] (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3,0.85);
    \draw[stealth-stealth](-1,0.55) -- (1,0.55) node[midway,fill=white]{68\%};
    \node at(0,0.5) {1 desviación};
    \node at(0,0.45) {estándar};    
    \draw[stealth-stealth](-2,0.7) -- (2,0.7) node[midway,fill=white]{95\%};
    \node at(0,0.65) {2 desviaciones estándar};
    \draw[stealth-stealth](-3,0.85) -- (3,0.85) node[midway,fill=white]{99.7\%};    
    \node at(0,0.8) {3 desviaciones estándar};  
    \addplot[samples=201,ultra thick] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
    \draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,{1/sqrt(2*pi)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces this figure:
[image: Standalone Test]

If I now try to put that figure inside a `beamer` presentation (using the `metropolis theme`), the code I am using is:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=8cm,
            hide y axis,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            xticklabels={$\bar x-3s$,$\bar x-2s$,$\bar x-s$,$\bar x$,$\bar x+s$,$\bar x+2s$,$\bar x+3s$},
            xmin = -3.5,
            xmax = 3.5,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 0.9,
          ]
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-3,0.85);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-2,0.7);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-1,0.55);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1,0.55);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:2,0.7);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3,0.85);
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-1,0.55) -- (1,0.55) node[midway,fill=white]{68\%};
        \node at(0,0.5) {1 desviación};
        \node at(0,0.45) {estándar};    
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-2,0.7) -- (2,0.7) node[midway,fill=white]{95\%};
        \node at(0,0.65) {2 desviaciones estándar};
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-3,0.85) -- (3,0.85) node[midway,fill=white]{99.7\%};    
        \node at(0,0.8) {3 desviaciones estándar};  
        \addplot[samples=201,ultra thick] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,{1/sqrt(2*pi)});
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces this when compiled:

[image: Beamer Test]

I have no clue about what is happening. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after a bit of detective work, it turns out that the problem is caused by

- the metropolis theme
- and therein from the `pgfplotsthemetol` package which is loaded at the end of the peramble
- which sets `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}`

as a workaround, use `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` after `\begin{document}`

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme
%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=8cm,
            hide y axis,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
            xticklabels={$\bar x-3s$,$\bar x-2s$,$\bar x-s$,$\bar x$,$\bar x+s$,$\bar x+2s$,$\bar x+3s$},
            xmin = -3.5,
            xmax = 3.5,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 0.9,
          ]
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-3,0.85);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-2,0.7);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:-1,0.55);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:1,0.55);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:2,0.7);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3,0.85);
        \begin{scope}
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-1,0.55) -- (1,0.55) node[midway,fill=white]{68\%};
        \node at(0,0.5) {1 desviación};
        \node at(0,0.45) {estándar};    
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-2,0.7) -- (2,0.7) node[midway,fill=white]{95\%};
        \node at(0,0.65) {2 desviaciones estándar};
        \draw[stealth-stealth](-3,0.85) -- (3,0.85) node[midway,fill=white]{99.7\%};    
        \node at(0,0.8) {3 desviaciones estándar}; 
                    \end{scope} 
        \addplot[samples=201,ultra thick] {exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)};
        \draw[thick,dashed] (axis cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:0,{1/sqrt(2*pi)});
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @samcarter! Indeed this solved the problem. I will warn the `metropolis`developers. I have no idea how the `LaTeX` engine works but shouldn't `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`override any previous version statement, even putting it in the preamble?

Comment: @RAO It does overwrite the previous statement, but metropolis instructs to load `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` at the end of the preamble and thus overwrites your statement which was issued before.

Comment: Oh I see. I will ask the `metropolis`developers to have a look at it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that the warning `Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': you might benefit from \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} (current compat level: 1.9).` will not go away, as it is likely emitted during the preamble processing. (But it works, yay!!)

Comment: @snwflk if you put `\AtEndPreamble{ \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} }` in your preamble (after loading the `metropolis` theme), there shouldn't be such an error.