# When to evaluate a custom math function in a `tikzpicture` environment using `pgfplots`

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath, tikzmath

I want to draw a custom function using `pgfplots`, and add an annotation node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    evaluate={
        function f(\x) {
            return cos(2*\x);
        };
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=-200,
        xmax=200,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5
        ]
        \addplot[
            domain=-180:180,
            samples=361
            ]{f(x)};
        % \node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,{f(45)}) {};
        \node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,0) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is:

[image: sample]

My question is about the commented line above, which cannot be compiled correctly. The reason, IMHO, is probably related to the function evaluation process (say, function `f` above). I am not quite understand the mechanism of it, so is there any way to solve this problem? An extra explanation is quite appreciated!

BTW: Instead of `evaluate`, I have also tried `declare function`, which works fine in this scenario; yet the actual custom function involves a complicated expression (defined in a recursive manner), which might not be handled by `declare function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commented code *does* work provided you load the `math` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    evaluate={
        function f(\x) {
            return cos(2*\x);
        };
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=-200,
        xmax=200,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5
        ]
        \addplot[
            domain=-180:180,
            samples=361
            ]{f(x)};
        \node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,{f(45)}) {};
        %\node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,0) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that it might be nontrivial to marry `math` to the `fpu` library, which `pgfplots` uses in its plots, in full glory. That is, if you want to play with recursive functions that work with integers, you may need to locally switch off `fpu`.

As for the question in the comments: there is a problem with `xelatex` or `lualatex` running on a `beamer` document including this code and using the `metropolis` theme. A probably related problem is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387875/194703). Among other things, `metropolis` sets the version of `pgfplots` to the value `1.9`. Here is a temporary workaround for that constellation. You need to choose a different variable for the function (which is of course just a placeholder, but this definitely should not be necessary). That is, use

```
evaluate={
    function f(\t) {
        return cos(2*\t);
    };
}
```

where `\x` got replaced by `\t`. Full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    >=stealth,
    evaluate={
        function f(\t) {
            return cos(2*\t);
        };
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=middle,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        xmin=-200,
        xmax=200,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5
        ]
        \addplot[%variable=\t,
            domain=-180:180,
            samples=361
            ]{f(x)};
        \node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,{f(45)}) {};
        %\node[coordinate,pin=above right:{$\cos 2x$}] at (axis cs:45,0) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just tried yours, it really works. The reason seems to be related to the `metropolis` beamer theme. When I use that theme, the error occurs. Maybe that is another story.

Comment: @oaheix Maybe there is yet another ingredient. When I wrap the above `tikzpicture` in `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{A plot} ... \end{frame}
\end{document}`, it also runs through on my updated TeXLive 2019 installation.

Comment: I tried it again using `pdflatex`, it works; yet it does not work using `xelatex` (which is used in my work) or `lualatex`.

Comment: @oaheix I tested this now explicitly on my updated TeXLive 2020 installation: here the above example works with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` and `xelatex`. However, the modified version with `beamer` and `metropolis` does not work with `lualatex` nor `xelatex`. It is also true that the `metropolis` theme has  the suspicious ingredient `\AtEndPreamble{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{pgfplots}{%
    \RequirePackage{pgfplotsthemetol}
  }{}
}` where `pgfplotsthemetol` does some weird things including `compat=1.9`. So seems like someone had to make some strange hard-coded choices for us.

Comment: @oaheix I added a workaround for that configuration. There seem to be issues with the interactions between `metropolis` and `pgfplots`.

Comment: Thank you again, and this solved the problem completely. Nice!