# Problem generating Tikz figure in Metropolis beamer theme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, beamer-metropolis

I have a normal distribution curve generated using Tikz that I would like to include in a beamer presentation. When I include the Tikz code inside a default beamer theme, it generates without errors:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage[outline]{contour} 
\contourlength{1.2pt}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

% to fill an area under function
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{\large Densité de la loi normale $N(\mu, \sigma)$}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
            \def\N{50}
            \def\B{11};
            \def\Bs{3.0};
            \def\xmax{\B+3.2*\Bs};
            \def\ymin{{-0.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}};
            \def\h{0.08*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)};
              
            \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
                        mark=none,domain={-0.05*(\xmax)}:{1.08*\xmax},samples=\N,smooth},
                        xmin={-0.1*(\xmax)}, xmax=\xmax,
                        ymin=\ymin, ymax={1.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)},
                        axis y line*=left,
                        axis x line*=bottom,
                        axis line style={draw=none},
                        ticks=none,
                        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
                        width=0.85*\textwidth, height=0.55*\textwidth,
                        y=700pt,
                        clip=false
                    ]
                        
                    % PLOTS
                    \addplot[blue,thick,name path=B] {gauss(x,\B,\Bs)};
                        
                    % FILL
                    \path[name path=xaxis]
                    (0,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0); 
                    \addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-3*\Bs}:{\B+3*\Bs}}];
                    \addplot[blue!25] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-2*\Bs}:{\B+2*\Bs}}];
                    \addplot[blue!10] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-1*\Bs}:{\B+1*\Bs}}];
                        
                    % LINES
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-3\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-2\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B-\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu-\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,line width=0.7pt]
                    coordinates {(\B,{1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}) (\B,{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+2\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+3\sigma$};
                        
                    \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \end{figure}
                    \end{frame}
                    
                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I include the same Tikz code inside a metropolis-themed beamer presentation, I obtain a very distorted result.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage[outline]{contour} 
\contourlength{1.2pt}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

% to fill an area under function
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{\large Densité de la loi normale $N(\mu, \sigma)$}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
            \def\N{50}
            \def\B{11};
            \def\Bs{3.0};
            \def\xmax{\B+3.2*\Bs};
            \def\ymin{{-0.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}};
            \def\h{0.08*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)};
              
            \begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
                        mark=none,domain={-0.05*(\xmax)}:{1.08*\xmax},samples=\N,smooth},
                        xmin={-0.1*(\xmax)}, xmax=\xmax,
                        ymin=\ymin, ymax={1.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)},
                        axis y line*=left,
                        axis x line*=bottom,
                        axis line style={draw=none},
                        ticks=none,
                        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
                        width=0.85*\textwidth, height=0.55*\textwidth,
                        y=700pt,
                        clip=false
                    ]
                        
                    % PLOTS
                    \addplot[blue,thick,name path=B] {gauss(x,\B,\Bs)};
                        
                    % FILL
                    \path[name path=xaxis]
                    (0,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0); 
                    \addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-3*\Bs}:{\B+3*\Bs}}];
                    \addplot[blue!25] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-2*\Bs}:{\B+2*\Bs}}];
                    \addplot[blue!10] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={domain={\B-1*\Bs}:{\B+1*\Bs}}];
                        
                    % LINES
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-3\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-2\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B-\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu-\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,line width=0.7pt]
                    coordinates {(\B,{1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}) (\B,{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+2\sigma$};
                    \addplot[black,dotted,thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt,scale=0.8] at ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+3\sigma$};
                        
                    \end{axis}
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                    \end{figure}
                    \end{frame}
                    
                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

What causes this? And what do I have to do so that the Tikz figure is rendered properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Firstly, I recommend removing the semicolons after the five `\def`s after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I removed the five semicolons but nothing changed, the same distorted figure you see above.

Comment: It seems the error stems from the package `pgfplotsthemetol` that is loaded by the theme.

Comment: Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387870/47927

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `metropolis` theme loads the package `pgfplotsthemetol` (which is part of the theme) if the `pgfplots` package is loaded. The `pgfplotsthemetol` package puts `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` at the very end of the preamble which overrides any other values you set to `compat` beforehand. I would consider this a bug.

The solution in your case is to replace `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` by `\AtEndPreamble{\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}}` which will put `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` even after the stuff inserted by the `pgfplotsthemetol` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage[outline]{contour} 
\contourlength{1.2pt}
\tikzset{>=latex} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
}

% to fill an area under function
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \caption{\large Densité de la loi normale $N(\mu, \sigma)$}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
            \def\N{50}
            \def\B{11}
            \def\Bs{3.0}
            \def\xmax{\B+3.2*\Bs}
            \def\ymin{{-0.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}}
            \def\h{0.08*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}
              
            \begin{axis}[
                every axis plot post/.append style={
                    mark=none,
                    domain={-0.05*(\xmax)}:{1.08*\xmax},
                    samples=\N,
                    smooth
                },
                xmin={-0.1*(\xmax)}, xmax=\xmax,
                ymin=\ymin, ymax={1.1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)},
                axis y line*=left,
                axis x line*=bottom,
                axis line style={draw=none},
                ticks=none,
                every axis x label/.style={
                    at={(current axis.right of origin)},
                    anchor=north
                },
                width=0.85*\textwidth, 
                height=0.55*\textwidth,
                y=700pt,
                clip=false
            ]
                    
                % PLOTS
                \addplot[blue, thick, name path=B] {gauss(x,\B,\Bs)};
                    
                % FILL
                \path[name path=xaxis]
                    (0,0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0); 
                \addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={
                    domain={\B-3*\Bs}:{\B+3*\Bs}}
                ];
                \addplot[blue!25] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={
                    domain={\B-2*\Bs}:{\B+2*\Bs}}
                ];
                \addplot[blue!10] fill between[of=xaxis and B, soft clip={
                    domain={\B-1*\Bs}:{\B+1*\Bs}}
                ];
                    
                % LINES
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-3\sigma$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu-2\sigma$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B-1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B-\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B-1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] at ({\B-\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu-\sigma$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, line width=0.7pt]
                    coordinates {(\B,{1*gauss(\B,\B,\Bs)}) (\B,{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] {\strut$\mu$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+1*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+1*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] at ({\B+\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+\sigma$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+2*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+2*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] at ({\B+2*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+2\sigma$};
                \addplot[black, dotted, thick]
                    coordinates {({\B+3*\Bs},{1*gauss(\B+3*\Bs,\B,\Bs)}) ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h})}
                    node[below=-3pt, scale=0.8] at ({\B+3*\Bs},{-\h}) {\strut$\mu+3\sigma$};
                        
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}      
\end{document}
```

[image]